# Can someone tell me what does this code mean?

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner learner for react.js please help

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.tıkla = this.tıkla.bind(this);
  
  }
  state={
    loggedIn:false
  }
  tıkla(){
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      loggedIn:!prevState.loggedIn   
      // false ise true yapcak 
    }))
  }
```

at the last function which names tıkla.why we did => this.

Comment: Can you be more specific please. What is your question excaly?

Comment: `=>` denotes an arrow function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: ı mean ı know how tu use set.state but ı didnt understand this prevState => action.

Comment: Better you follow a es 6 tutorial, this is called arrow function in js, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrow-functions-in-javascript/ check here or any other "es6 arrow function" result in google search.

Comment: What kind of funny _i_ you use.

Comment: ı am lazy to make an upper case sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a reactjs class component.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.tıkla = this.tıkla.bind(this);
  
  }
```

This is the constructor, where props (read arguments) and local functions are bound to the class.

```
state={
    loggedIn:false
  }
```

This is the state, where they are setting the default value of loggedIn as false.

```
tıkla(){
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      loggedIn:!prevState.loggedIn   
      // false ise true yapcak 
    }))
  }
```

This is the function in which they are changing the state of loggedIn, here => is called a fat arrow and this is lambda function. prevState is the objected passed, in this specific example, it holds the current value of state loggedIn. For example: if loggedIn is false then, calling this function will make loggedIn as true due to the not operator.

You can read about react state [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and regarding es6 arrow function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: If it has answered your question, please mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: ı am waiting :)